# How to solve equation having summation?

Tags: r, sum, equation-solving

I solve equation `sum((2*x+1)/k^x)==3*k` (where x belongs to Whole Numbers) as

```
x=0:10000
y=function(k){sum((2*x+1)/k^x)==3*k}
y(2)
```

It returns `TRUE`.

But I want a method to solve it automatically, how should I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try function `uniroot`:

```
uniroot(function(k){sum((2*x+1)/k^x)-3*k}, c(0,100))$root
#[1] 2.000019

uniroot(function(k){sum((2*x+1)/k^x)-3*k}, c(1,10))$root
#[1] 2
```

Also in the first call, you don't get exactly `2` probably because of number representation so you may need to add a tolerance; See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) for more on the subject.

Comment: Nice, can I extend x to infinity?

Comment: @HemantRupani to `Inf` you mean ? I don't think so but it may depend on your computer (also, with very large number as "upper bound" for x, it may take a lot of time to compute the root)